# trasfer one excel sheet into multiple xml content in mule

Tags: xml, excel, mule, mule-studio

In mule I'm using data-mapper to convert excel file to xml file.
data mapper is working fine. But i want one excel file different xml format.

My configuration xml:

```
 <data-mapper:config name="ms_excel_to_xml_2" transformationGraphPath="ms_excel_to_xml_2.grf" doc:name="ms_excel_to_xml_2"/>
    <jms:activemq-connector name="Active_MQ1" brokerURL="tcp://10.16.20.132:61616" validateConnections="true" doc:name="Active MQ" password="manager" username="system" specification="1.1"/>
    <flow name="file-processFlow1" doc:name="file-processFlow1">
        <file:inbound-endpoint path="C:\Users\rajesh.narravula\Desktop\New folder" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File" fileAge="50000">
            <file:filename-regex-filter pattern=".*.xlsx" caseSensitive="false"/>
        </file:inbound-endpoint>
        <data-mapper:transform doc:name="MS Excel To XML" config-ref="ms_excel_to_xml_2" />
        <jms:outbound-endpoint doc:name="JMS" queue="OrchestratorQueue" connector-ref="Active_MQ1" responseTimeout="0">
            <jms:transaction action="ALWAYS_BEGIN" timeout="10000"/>
        </jms:outbound-endpoint>
    </flow>
```

This is my excel file content:

```
caseType    claimNo status  customerName
------------------------------------------
CashLess      9     Open    Varun Arya
CashLess      9     Open    Varun Arya
```

Actual xml(after datamapper) I'm getting was(as String):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CashLess>
  <caseType>CashLess</caseType>
  <claimNo>9</claimNo>
  <status>Open</status>
  <customerName>Varun Arya</customerName>
</CashLess>
<CashLess>
  <caseType>CashLess</caseType>
  <claimNo>9</claimNo>
  <status>Open</status>
  <customerName>Varun Arya</customerName>
</CashLess>
```

expected is(Multiple String objects):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CashLess>
  <caseType>CashLess</caseType>
  <claimNo>9</claimNo>
  <status>Open</status>
  <customerName>Varun Arya</customerName>
</CashLess>

*another one*

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CashLess>
  <caseType>CashLess</caseType>
  <claimNo>9</claimNo>
  <status>Open</status>
  <customerName>Varun Arya</customerName>
</CashLess>
```

Please any one help what changes i want to do. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. 1.Convert excel to JSON.
2. Convert JSON to expression.
3. Use collection-splitter.
4. convert Object to JSON.
5. Then convert JSON to XML.

sample code:

> ```
> <data-mapper:config name="ms_excel_to_json_1" transformationGraphPath="ms_excel_to_json_1.grf" doc:name="ms_excel_to_json_1"/>
> <data-mapper:config name="json_to_xml" transformationGraphPath="json_to_xml.grf" doc:name="json_to_xml"/>
> <data-mapper:config name="json_to_xml_1" transformationGraphPath="json_to_xml_1.grf" doc:name="json_to_xml_1"/>
> <flow name="file-processFlow1" doc:name="file-processFlow1">
>     <file:inbound-endpoint path="C:\Users\hello\Desktop\New folder" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File" fileAge="50000">
>         <file:filename-regex-filter pattern=".*.xlsx" caseSensitive="false"/>
>     </file:inbound-endpoint>
>     <data-mapper:transform config-ref="ms_excel_to_json_1" doc:name="MS Excel To JSON"/>
>     <json:json-to-object-transformer returnClass="java.util.List" doc:name="JSON to Object"/>
>     <expression-transformer expression="#[message.payload]" doc:name="Expression"/>
>     <collection-splitter doc:name="Collection Splitter"/>
>     <json:object-to-json-transformer doc:name="Object to JSON"/>
>     <data-mapper:transform config-ref="json_to_xml_1" doc:name="JSON To XML"/>
>     <object-to-string-transformer doc:name="Object to String"/>
> </flow>
> ```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Place a splitter with an XPath expression after DataMapper and write each individual record to  a file.

http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Splitter+Flow+Control+Reference